# AP Calculus BC question

Tags: calculus

I recently came across an AP Calculus question:

The length of the arc of the parabola $4x=y2$ cut off by the line $x=2$ is given by the integral

a)$\int_{- 1}^1 \sqrt( x^2 +1 ) dx $

b)  $\int_{- 1}^1 \sqrt( 1+x ) dx$

c)$ 1/2 \int _0^2\sqrt( 4+y^2 ) dy     $

d) $\int _{-1}^1\sqrt( 4+y^2 ) dy     $

My answer:

The parabola is symmetric to the $x$-axis and for$ x=2, y = +-\sqrt(8)$

Which means the integral should be:

$2\int_{-2\sqrt(2)}^0 {\sqrt( 4 + y^2 ) dy}$]  $
But that isn't even an option. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: use $$\LaTeX$$ please!

Comment: You are finding the area cut off, not the arc length cut off.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be option (C). To find arc lengths, you should use Pythagoras theorem to differential triangles with sides dx and dy, and then substitute dy/dx from given function.

Comment: That is what I did. Also the answer at the back of the book is option (d).